# Sum of the diagonal in a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

```
for (row=0; row<SIZE; row++)
    {
        for (col=0; col<SIZE; col++)
        {
            if (row == 0 && col == 0) {
                answer+=my_data[row][col];
            }
            else if ((row)/(col) == 1) //1 is slope of array
            {
                answer+=my_data[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The diagonal sum of the 8x8 array is: %i\n",answer);
```

starting from `[0,0]` and ending at `[8,8]`

> "Sum the diagonal values inside the
>   8x8 array starting at [0,0]"

I realize I can do a single for loop since the shape is just 1:1 but how would I do it just in case I need to sum a diagonal 8x10 array?

Comment: If you really want that data you need to use interpolation and perhaps even filtering to achieve it (basic idea is to step with proption to other axis length). If its for matrix data (ie linear combinations) you should consider the answer from @codaddict

Comment: In a 2x3 array, what elements belong to the *diagonal*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Diagonal element(s) and main diagonal are defined only for a square matrix.

```
if rowcount == colcount
  sum = 0
  for i = 0 to rowcount
    sum += matrix[i][i]
  end-for
else
  print Diagonal sum not defined
end-if
```

For a non-square matrix if you want to sum the elements at position with equal row and column number you can do:

```
sum = 0
for i = 0 to min(rowcount,colcount)
  sum += matrix[i][i]
end-for
print sum
```

Comment: So a single for loop is the only way?

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you will define diagonal elements. If we define diagonal elements as - *cells through which diagonal line passes somewhere NEAR the center of cell*, then diagonal elements of matrix:

[image]

(0,0);(1,0);(2,1);(3,1);(4,2);(5,2) will be perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Well the primary concern over here is, what's the definition of diagonal elements if it's not a square matrix. If it's a square matrix then it should be RowCount==ColCount. But what if it's not a square matrix??

Comment: I understand that part but then I thought about the slope of the array. I can take the slope of the array and only take the numbers that equal that slope. The "points" of the slope inside the array would be my diagonal.

Comment: if it's a 2 x 3 matrix , I don't think you would be able to retrieve all the elements even if the slope is tabulated :-)

Comment: eg: In 2 x 3matrix (0,0) and (1,2) elements would be considered if slope is taken into consideration

Answer (score 0):

codaddict is right; only square matrixes have diagonal elements.
I suppose you want addition of elements where rownum==colnum?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to ignore the excess rows or columns if it's non-square; that seems like the most reasonable approach, although that is just a guess since the diagonal of a non-square matrix isn't defined, but since you're asking about 2-dim array instead of a matrix, I presume the context of the question is a programming assignment, rather than linear algebra.

To do this, you can get the min length of row & column and then iterate from 0 to that min length:

```
diag_len = min (row_size, col_size);

for (int i = 0; i < /* or <= */ diag_len; i++) {
  answer += my_data[i][i];
}
```

This works in both the square and lossy non-square cases. Your example code ends up considering the coordinates of every cell which is wasteful when you know you only care about the cases where row == col. (It also obviates the need for a special case when row & col are both 0 *and* avoids division, which is a slower CPU operation than addition.)

Comment: OTOH, your slope approach isn't necessarily bad either, depending on the context. For example, if we're talking about an image, which would be an NxM array of pixels, then a non-square diagonal is less ambiguous--it's just a line between opposite corners.

Answer (score -2):

## include

int main(){

int a[10][10],i,j,sum=0,m,n;

printf("\nEnter the row and column of matrix: ");
  scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);

printf("\nEnter the elements of matrix: ");

Comment: This is not an answer on the question